# Laravel 5.6 php artisan route:list shwoing only api middleware why?

Tags: laravel, rest, api

I am trying to make api from laravel5.6, its works but both are not wotrking, I am not able to run website, because web route not working 
in route list shpwing on api middleware why?

```html
$ php artisan route:list
+--------+----------------------------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method                                 | URI                | Name     | Action                                           | Middleware |
+--------+----------------------------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS | api/en/v1/gettoken | gettoken | App\Http\Controllers\Api\ApiController@gettoken  | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS | api/en/v1/login    | login    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController@login    | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|OPTIONS | api/en/v1/register | register | App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController@register | api        |
```

Comment: Hi, you need to separate the web routes from api. routes/api.php is for API only (using api middleware), web.php is using Web middleware

Answer (score 0):

Write your routes in routes/web.php. all routes in api.php are uses the api middleware.